# Keep 3 recent copies of files with similar names and delete others

Tags: powershell

I have a folder full of SQL backups with names that are very similar.  I want to keep the 3 most recent copies regardless of date backed up for each facility and in the future use Task Scheduler to keep a rolling 3 days copy of those files.  The setup is like this:

Backup_DB_Facility_AAAA_backup_2023_05_01.bak
Backup_DB_Facility_BBBB_backup_2023_05_01.bak
Backup_DB_Facility_CCCC_backup_2023_05_01.bak

Currently facilites AAAA, BBBB, and CCCC have backups for 05/01 - 05/10.

The powershell I have currently is:

```
$RCDestination = \\computername\\folder
$FileName = "Backup_DB_Facility\*"

Get-ChildItem -Path $RCDestination | where {(-not $\_.PsIsContainer) -and ($FileName -like "$FileName")} | sort Name | select -Skip 3| Remove-Item -Force
```

This works but it keeps the most recent 3 of only facility AAAA.  I need a way to tell powershell to differentiate between the file names for facilities AAAA, BBBB, CCCC.  The naming convention can't be changed as it is set by company standards.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this will help you.

```
$RCDestination = \\computername\\folder

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $RCDestination -File | Select-Object -Property *,@{N = 'Facility'; E = { $PSItem.Name.Split('_')[3] }}
$filesGrouped = $files | Group-Object -Property Facility

foreach ($facility in $filesGrouped) {
    $filesToRemove = $facility.Group | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Skip 3
    Get-ChildItem -Path $filesToRemove.FullName | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

I added a calculated column to the files that extracts the facility. Then I group by facility, which allows me to go through each group of files and select all but the most recent 3.